# Print values in php array

Tags: php, arrays, echo

I have a problem with this php code.

```
$q=$cn->exec('call get_count(1,@no_of_users)');
$res=$cn->query('select @no_of_users')->fetchAll();
echo "users".$res['@no_of_users']; 
print_r($res);
```

I get this output.

```
usersArray ( [0] => Array ( [@no_of_users] => 3 [0] => 3 ) )
```

Can anyone tell me how to echo  value 3 only. That means I need to show the value of '@no_of_users'.

Comment: `$res[0]['@no_of_users']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do as

```
echo $res[0]["@no_of_users"];
```

Answer (score 0):

If $cn holds PDO instance use fetchColumn() instead of fetchAll()